# SQL Server Rank() Over Partition w/Back and Forth values

Tags: sql, sql-server, window-functions

I am using the following query against a TFS database.  The workitem in question goes from Active to other states and back to active.  I'd like to use Rank() Over Partition to treat the two sets of "Active" states as separate groups rather than continuing the numbering of the second Active group where it left off with the first Active group.

```
;with cte as
(
    SELECT 
        dense_rank() over(partition by ID, State order by ID,  Rev) as rn
        , ID
        , Rev
        , State
        , Reason
        , NamePart
        --, *
    FROM dbo.WorkItemsWere Hist
        Left JOIN Constants Cs WITH (nolock)
            ON Hist.[Changed by] = Cs.ConstID

    WHERE ID = 38728
)
SELECT * 
FROM cte
--WHERE rn = 1
ORDER BY ID, Rev
```

Below is the resultset I get with an additional column of "Desired rn" thrown in to show what I'd like it to be:

```
Desired rn rn    ID          Rev         State                            
---------- ----- ----------- ----------- -----------------------------------
1          1     38728       1           Proposed                            
1          1     38728       2           Active                              
2          2     38728       3           Active                              
3          3     38728       4           Active                              
4          4     38728       5           Active                              
5          5     38728       6           Active                              
6          6     38728       7           Active                              
7          7     38728       8           Active                              
1          1     38728       9           Dev Complete                        
1          1     38728       10          Resolved; Queued for Build to Test  
2          2     38728       11          Resolved; Queued for Build to Test  
3          3     38728       12          Resolved; Queued for Build to Test 
1          8     38728       13          Active                             
2          9     38728       14          Active                             
1          2     38728       15          Dev Complete
```

Can this be done by tweaking the syntax?

Answer (score 2):

Using difference of `ROW_NUMBERS`:

```
WITH CteGrp AS(
    SELECT *,
        Grp = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY Rev)
                - ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ID, State ORDER BY Rev)
    FROM tbl
),
Cte AS(
    SELECT *,
        rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ID, Grp ORDER BY Rev)
    FROM CteGrp
)
SELECT
    rn, ID, Rev, State 
FROM Cte
ORDER BY ID, Rev
```

<kbd>[**DEMO**](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/447381)</kbd>

---

*Read Jeff Moden's article for more info on this technique:*

*[Group Islands of Contiguous Dates (SQL Spackle) - SQLServerCentral](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/71550/)*

Comment: Very elegant!  Worked perfectly!  Thank you Jeff!  And thank you Felix for pointing out the technique/article!